# How do I make sure that my first tab always displays?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar

I have:

1. A WebViewFragment that just displays a WebView for a given URL.
2. A TabbedWebViewHandler that handles creating tabs that contain WebViewFragments and adding them to the action bar.
3. A HelpActivity that creates and displays 4 WebViewFragments (for "further information", "terms and conditions", "credits" and "purpose of this app" help screens respectively).

All of this works fine, *except* the first tab is always just a blank black screen when the HelpActivity first starts:

[image: blank Android tab]

The other tabs work fine, and the first tab (in this case the "info" tab) will render it's web view properly if another tab is selected and then the "info" tab is reselected.

I always select the first tab after I've created it and added it to the action bar tabs with `actionBar.selectTab(newTab);`. I know that the code to do this is running, because the log contains "selecting first tab".

I'm also using the TabbedWebViewHandler for other activities that do the same thing (including for activities that only have one "tab" and so don't display the tab navigation), so I'd prefer to fix TabbedWebViewHandler instead of putting a workaround in HelpActivity.

I'm using ActionBarSherlock / the Android support library to provide my tab functionality if that's relevant.

How can I make sure that the first tab of my activity is always displayed properly?

#### WebViewFragment

```
public class WebViewFragment extends Fragment {
    private static final String TAG = WebViewFragment.class.getSimpleName();
    private String url;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(
            LayoutInflater inflater,
            ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d(TAG, String.format("onCreateView(): URL is '%s'", url));
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.snippet_webview, container, false);
        WebView wv = (WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.webViewWebView);
        wv.loadUrl(url);
        return v;
    }
    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }
}
```

#### TabbedWebViewHandler

```
public class TabbedWebViewHandler {
    private static final String TAG = "TabbedWebViewHandler";
    private final ActionBar actionBar;
    private final Context hostContext;
    private final FragmentManager fragmentManager;
    public TabbedWebViewHandler(SherlockFragmentActivity host) {
        this.hostContext = (Context) host;
        this.actionBar = host.getSupportActionBar();
        this.fragmentManager = host.getSupportFragmentManager();
    }
    public void addTab(String title, String renderUrl) {
        Tab newTab = makeTab(title, renderUrl);
        actionBar.addTab(newTab);
        // FIXME: buggy! tabs don't show on first load
        if (actionBar.getTabCount() == 1) {
            /* first tab: select it by default */
            Log.d(TAG, "Selecting first tab");
            actionBar.selectTab(newTab);
        }
        if (actionBar.getTabCount() > 1) { 
            /* more than one tab: enable navigating between tabs */
            actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        }
    }
    private Tab makeTab(String title, String renderUrl) {
        WebViewFragment f = 
                (WebViewFragment) 
                    SherlockFragment.instantiate(
                        hostContext, 
                        WebViewFragment.class.getName());
        f.setUrl(renderUrl);
        ActionBar.TabListener l = new WebViewFragmentTabListener(f);
        Tab newTab = actionBar.newTab();
        newTab.setText(title);
        newTab.setTabListener(l);
        return newTab;
    }
    private class WebViewFragmentTabListener implements ActionBar.TabListener {
        private final WebViewFragment fragment;
        public WebViewFragmentTabListener(WebViewFragment f) {
            this.fragment = f;
        }
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            // replace current fragment with this fragment
            if (ft == null) { 
                fragmentManager
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .replace(android.R.id.content, fragment)
                    .commit();
            } else {
                ft.replace(android.R.id.content, fragment);
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            ft.remove(fragment);
        }
        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            // do nothing
        }
    }
}
```

#### HelpActivity

```
public class HelpActivity extends BaseActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "HelpActivity";
    private static final String FURTHER_URL = 
            "file:///android_asset/further_info.html";
    private static final String DISCLAIMER_URL = 
            "file:///android_asset/terms_and_conditions.html";
    private static final String CREDITS_URL = 
            "file:///android_asset/image_credits.html";
    private static final String PURPOSE_URL = 
            "file:///android_asset/purpose.html";
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onCreate()");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        TabbedWebViewHandler twvh = new TabbedWebViewHandler(this);
        twvh.addTab("Info", FURTHER_URL);
        twvh.addTab("Terms", DISCLAIMER_URL);
        twvh.addTab("Credits", CREDITS_URL);
        twvh.addTab("Purpose", PURPOSE_URL);
    }

}
```

#### Log output

```
I/HelpActivity(20038): onCreate()
D/TabbedWebViewHandler(20038): Selecting first tab
D/WebViewFragment(20038): onCreateView(): URL is file:///android_asset/further_info.html
I/webclipboard(20038): clipservice: android.sec.clipboard.ClipboardExManager@41d57ff8
D/WebViewFragment(20038): onCreateView(): URL is file:///android_asset/further_info.html
I/webclipboard(20038): clipservice: android.sec.clipboard.ClipboardExManager@41d57ff8
D/WebViewFragment(20038): onCreateView(): URL is file:///android_asset/further_info.html
I/webclipboard(20038): clipservice: android.sec.clipboard.ClipboardExManager@41d57ff8
```

Comment: I'd try two things here.
1. Set navigation mode to tabs before adding adding tabs. 
2. in onTabSelected use the fragment transaction from arguments and dont invoke commit() yourself.

Comment: I tried the second point (using the fragment transaction from the arguments), and found that the "ft" variable passed in is null sometimes (at least on first load). From the doco on those methods, I think it's only set when onTabUnselected() is called first: "this tab's unselect and the newly selected tab's select will be executed in a single transaction".

I tried `if (ft == null) { ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction(); }` but then I get a NullPointerException "at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeFragment(FragmentManager.java:1165)".

I'll try the first point next...

Comment: OK, the onTabSelected() code is now updated to: create a new fragment transaction and then commit on it if there's no existing fragment transaction OR use the existing fragment transaction and NOT commit on it if there is an existing fragment transaction available. See the (edited) code above. That seems to work (i.e. not crash), but it doesn't solve the problem of the first loaded tab being blank until it's unselected and then reselected.

Comment: try making WebView a private property in WebViewFragment. When you set the url, do the `if(wv != null )wv.loadUrl(url); `

Comment: @TheoWHtet: OK, I've done that - now all of the tabs are blank white (i.e. a webview with nothing loaded). setUrl() is called from HelpActivity.onCreate() -> TWVH.addTab() -> TWVH.makeTab() -> WVF.setUrl(), and HelpActivity.onCreate() occurs before the WVF.onCreateView() (where I'm currently loading the URL).

It's a bit brittle, but the setUrl() is *always* called before the fragment onCreateView() runs. There's evidence of that in that the log always contains "onCreateView(): URL is 'file:///android_asset/further_info.html'" (or similar) and *never* contains "onCreateView(): URL is 'null'"

Comment: @BartoszFilipowicz: hah, setting the navigation mode to tabs before adding the tabs fixes things. It's a bit odd, because the "info" tab definitely *appears* to be selected in the screenshot above - but I guess not being in "tab navigation" when I add the first tab causes problems when I eventually switch to "tab navigation". If you want to add your comment as an answer I'll award you the bounty.

Comment: if setUrl is called before onCreateView how about try loading it in onResume?

Comment: @George Cool. I'd have to dig deeper into actionbar's code to see why this is happening. Probably the fragment creation event is not triggered, when the mode is not set to NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the navigation mode to `ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS` before you start adding tabs.

edit: 
Found it! 
There's a passage in [action bar's selectTab() method](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/blob/master/library/src/com/actionbarsherlock/internal/app/ActionBarImpl.java#L503):

```
if (getNavigationMode() != NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS) {
    mSavedTabPosition = tab != null ? tab.getPosition() : INVALID_POSITION;
    return;
}
```

which basically prevents tab initialization if the bar is not in `ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS`.

Comment: Thanks heaps for your answer Bartosz - especially for going the extra mile and finding the code responsible.